# stop a service in catch

Tags: vb.net, service, abort

It seems like this should be simple but i can't find it.   On some of my try/catch blocks I want to actually stop the service from continueing to execute.  I usually use application.exit but that doesn't work in the service.

```
    Public Sub LogMessages(ByRef _msg As String, ByRef _method As String, Optional _errNum As Int16 = 0, Optional _errType As String = "I", Optional _
                        _abort As Boolean = False, Optional _checkErrorTable As Boolean = False)

    .....logging code here


    If _abort Then
        LogMessages("Aborting", Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, 900, "E")
        'what to do to stop program here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Application.Exit` work exactly?!  I just opened a service project of mine, thinking I'd find the answer to your question, and found I was using Application.Exit (the service has been in use for 3 years now with no issues!).  As an alternative, you could try `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()`, but I'm not sure if that's the recommended way to terminate a whole application.

Comment: When I use intellisense,  Application is not available.  Am i missing an import? I'm using Visual Studios 2010.

Comment: Yes, it's in `System.Windows.Forms`.  I can understand why you wouldn't want to import that namespace, but it won't cause any problems if you only use the safe parts of it!

Comment: Environment.Exit seems to work.   I knew it was simple

Comment: Yes, I agree that is the most appropriate!  Please add it as the answer.